# c# Problems with repeated console.writeline commands

Tags: c#, .net, console

I am coding a c# command line application (WIN7, 64bit) that should write many lines to the command line.

I cooked the problem down to the following code:

```
        int lineno;
        for (lineno = 0; lineno < 100000; lineno++) { 
            Console.WriteLine(">" + lineno);
        }
```

I can't understand why the apllication dies after 39404 lines:

`...`
`>39401`
`>39402`
`>39403`
`>39404`
`"Console Application has stopped working."`

Please let me know if you have any ideas what went wrong here.

Thank you & best regards, Dirk.

Comment: hi, if you put a try-catch do you catch anything?

Comment: I tried the same code with WinXP SP3, x86 machine and its working fine.

Comment: Tried it on my win7 64bit. no problem here. ran all the way to the end.

Comment: are you using any non-standard command line interpreter?

Comment: I just ran your code snippet and it worked fine for me.

Comment: The message `Console Application has stopped working.` has to be coming from *you*, so in what circumstance are you printing out that message?

Comment: @Dirk : Post your *entire* code.Also tell us what are you using to run this C# program ? You must have something done wrong. Posting code helps developers here to analyze what went wrong.

Comment: @ SO : I am not getting, why this question is being  upvoted ? It doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: @SO : Closing this question ? What say ?

Comment: Downvote. **Post complete source code.**

Answer (score 2):

I doubt your question. Because my program works fine and shows till 99999 under MS Visual Studio 2008.

[image]

---

**EDIT :** After Dirk commented on Davido's answer, with `Console.WriteLine(">>>" + lineno);` the output prints many 36251 times.  But that's incorrect. With ">>>" also, program accurately works.

Here's image for same.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the problem--it seems the problem is environment.

Does it always fail at `39404`? Does it fail after a certain period of time? How do you launch it? Have you tried launching it from command line? Are you sure this is all code that you have? Have you tried building it with different configurations?

Answering these questions, you might find what causes the problem.

**Edit:** the oddest thing I see about it is this message:

> "Console Application has stopped working."

**It's obviously not system or framework message.**
Please post complete code because it looks like you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Hello Gaeron, Thanks for your support. - I alway start the program from the command line. - I tried a Thread.Sleep(10) for each loop, nothing changes. - Its allways the same line - I use the standard cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my system. (Windows 7, VS 2010).

[image: Screenshot]

What Operating System and Framework version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your application target to compile for x86. Sometimes this solves strange issues I have with different projects.

### Edit:

Dirk, try making a NEW project and putting your code in a blank console project. See if that changes how it outputs. I suspect that doing this will change the number of lines you are able to write. If so, then there is a problem with some of your other code that you haven't posted. Just something you might want to consider.

Comment: If I change the code to: console.writeLine(">>>.. (Three ">") I get only 36251 lines :-(

Comment: Hi, I did created a new project and just copied the loop into it. This seems to work fine. It think that the problem is caused by the "ftcjtag.dll", a dll that works fine at 32 and 64 bit windows but causes errors during debug run on 64 bit machines. The message says that the stack is corupted.

Comment: I also tried to compile the code for x86, but from the comments I found on the web this seems not be possible with express :-( .